# Сборка своего окружения

Tags: linux, debian

Здравствуйте, решил ознакомиться с линукс.
Поставил debian, решил начать с внешнего вида, потому что планирую поставить эту систему на ноут и использовать на постоянной основе. Чуть позже я попробую другие дистрибутивы, но решил начать с дебиана, потому что слышал что он очень стабильный.

Гном мне не нравится, KDE слишком перегружено, мне хочется собрать своё окружение.
Я удалил все окружения и сейчас у меня обычная консоль.

На сколько я понимаю, мне нужен оконный менеджер и панель, ну и для теста, какое-нибудь приложение, например файловый менеджер.

Мне нравится KWin, с панелью я ещё не определился, но наверное это будет xfce4-panel.

**Проблема в том,** что я не знаю как должен выглядеть процесс сборки.
Я думал что мне нужно будет выполнить `apt-get install kwin-common`, поставится оконный менеджер и я смогу его как-то запустить и попаду в графический интерфейс, но прописав команду, оказалось что у меня уже установлен этот пакет, а я все ещё в консоли.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне следует сделать, что бы я получил рабочее окружение из запчастей которые нравятся мне, а не из готовых сборок. Перечислите минимальные составляющие окружения.

**P.S.** [на этой странице](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29#.D0.A1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B0) есть список составляющих, на сколько я понимаю, самые важные из них, это как раз **оконный менеджер** и **панель задач**, но судя по всему, этого не достаточно, что я упускаю?

Comment: вам нужен какой нибудь `display manager`, там вы сможете настроить вход в ваш `window manager`

Comment: я бы посоветовал начать с arch linux. Он гораздо сложнее в установке, но на выходе Вы получите пустую ОС, а мануалов по настройке интерфейса на него очень много. Предварительно загуглите связку Ваших "запчастей" на arch linux, чтобы удостовериться в том, что не зря ставите эту ОС.

Comment: @rOtK9 да, уже понял. Спасибо

Comment: а можно просто поставить xfce, он хорошо настраивается, минимально перегружен. Тем более, что панельку с него Вы уже решили взять.

Comment: @rOtK9 поставил  display и window менеджеры. Сейчас система выглядит [так](https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2018/02/09f5c936a9c43c23364781cf5b19ec4a.png) (это сборка из рандомных компонентов, просто то, что получилось поставить без проблем, одной командой, это временно, сейчас важно понять принцип). Теперь мне нужен рабочий стол, что бы всякие папки и ярлыки складывать на экране. Подскажите название этого типа компонентов.

Comment: @Петр скиньте пожалуйста менеджеры, которые Вы использовали. Все зависит от них. Но обычно используются `.desktop` файлы  Вы можете загуглить их как `desktop entries`. Это своего рода ярлыки, хранящие путь к приложению и его метаданные

Comment: Для настройки обоев рабочего стола загуглите `feh` или `nitrogen` - они минималистичные и их легко настроить. Обои не зависят от `window manager`

Comment: Советую попробовать [Awesome](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome) + [Ly](https://github.com/cylgom/ly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. конечно, вам нужен [*x-сервер*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). все необходимое может быть установлено по зависимостям от мета-пакета `xorg`. возможно, он уже установлен у вас в системе и вы вручную поудаляли какие-то из зависимостей этого мета-пакета. тогда, чтобы зависимости установились заново, сначала удалите этот мета-пакет:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove xorg
   ```
2. следующий необходимый компонент — [*display manager*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)). в принципе, конечно, [можно обойтись и без него](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/X_without_Display_Manager), но проще будет установить какой-нибудь минимальный из списка менеджеров:

   ```
   $ apt-cache search x-display-manager | sort
   gdm3 - GNOME Display Manager
   lightdm - simple display manager
   lxdm - LXDE display manager
   nodm - automatic display manager
   sddm - modern display manager for X11
   slim - desktop-independent graphical login manager for X11
   wdm - WINGs Display Manager - an xdm replacement with a WindowMaker look
   xdm - X display manager
   ```

   самый минималистичный из них — это `nodm`, но у него проявился [пока не исправленный баг](https://github.com/spanezz/nodm/issues/5), связанный со взаимодействием с *systemd*.

   следующий по минимализму — пожалуй, *xdm*
3. ну и, конечно, нужен [*window manager*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_X_Window_System) (список был чуть больше, я удалил из него несколько лишних пунктов):

   ```
   $ apt-cache search x-window-manager | sort
   9wm - X11 window manager inspired by Plan 9's rio
   aewm - minimalist window manager for X11
   aewm++ - minimal window manager written in C++
   afterstep - window manager with the NEXTSTEP look and feel
   amiwm - The Amiga look alike window manager
   awesome - highly configurable X window manager
   blackbox - Window manager for X
   bspwm - Binary space partitioning window manager
   clfswm - A(nother) Common Lisp FullScreen Window Manager
   compiz - OpenGL window and compositing manager
   ctwm - Claude's Tab window manager
   cwm - lightweight and efficient window manager for X11
   dwm - dynamic window manager
   e17 - Enlightenment DR17 Window Manager
   evilwm - minimalist window manager for X11
   fluxbox - Highly configurable and low resource X11 Window manager
   flwm - Fast Light Window Manager
   fvwm1 - Old version of the F(?) Virtual Window Manager
   fvwm-crystal - Pretty Desktop Environment based on FVWM
   fvwm - F(?) Virtual Window Manager
   herbstluftwm - manual tiling window manager for X11
   i3-wm - improved dynamic tiling window manager
   icewm - wonderful Win95-OS/2-Motif-like window manager
   jwm - very small lightweight pure X11 window manager with tray and menus
   kwin-x11 - KDE window manager, X11 version
   lwm - lightweight window manager
   marco - lightweight GTK+ window manager for MATE
   matchbox-window-manager - window manager for resource-limited systems
   metacity - lightweight GTK+ window manager
   miwm - minimalist window manager with virtual workspaces
   muffin - lightweight window and compositing manager
   mutter - lightweight GTK+ window manager
   mwm - Motif Window Manager
   notion - tiling tabbed window manager designed for keyboard users
   openbox - standards-compliant, fast, light-weight and extensible window manager
   oroborus - A lightweight themeable windowmanager for X
   pekwm - very light window manager
   ratpoison - keyboard-only window manager
   sapphire - A minimal but configurable X11R6 window manager
   sawfish - window manager for X11
   spectrwm - dynamic tiling window manager
   stumpwm - tiling, keyboard driven Common Lisp window manager
   subtle - grid-based manual tiling window manager
   tinywm - tiny window manager
   tritium - tabbed/tiling window manager
   twm - Tab window manager
   vtwm - Virtual Tab Window Manager
   w9wm - enhanced window manager based on 9wm
   windowlab - small and simple Amiga-like window manager
   wm2 - small, unconfigurable window manager
   wmaker - NeXTSTEP-like window manager for X
   wmii - lightweight tabbed and tiled X11 window manager, version 3
   xfwm4 - window manager of the Xfce project
   xmonad - Lightweight X11 window manager written in Haskell
   ```

   вам, вроде бы, *kwin* импонирует, значит нужен пакет `kwin-x11`.

---

итого:

1. удаляем на всякий случай (если был установлен) мета-пакет `xorg`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove xorg
   ```
2. устанавливаем выбранные пакеты:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install xorg xdm kwin-x11
   ```

   на развёрнутом из [образа *netinstall*](https://mirror.yandex.ru/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/) дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* версии `9.3` (`stretch`) потребовалось доустановить 856 пакетов (можно было не устанавливать рекомендуемые пакеты, добавив опцию `--no-install-recommends`).
3. перезапускаем установленный *display manager* (`xdm`):

   ```
   $ sudo service xdm restart
   ```

   или перезагружаем систему и получаем (после ввода логина-пароля в приглашении *xdm-а*) симпатичный чёрненький экран с красивеньким стильным курсором:

[image: kwin]

это всё, что умеет выбранный вами *window manager* `kwm`. чтобы можно было как-то продуктивно пользоваться графической средой, надо либо заменить *wm* на что-то более полноценное (какой-нибудь там *icewm* и т.п.) или дополнить систему каким-нибудь [*desktop environment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_desktop_environments) (правда, если это не `kde`, то у него, скорее всего, будет собственный *window manager*), либо попробовать дополнить экран какими-нибудь панельками-менюшками-свистелками-и-тд-и-тп (описание этих процессов не привожу, так как это слишком утяжелит и без того немаленький ответ).

---

конечно, можно было сделать и проще, поступившись гибкостью выбора компонентов. например, установить какой-нибудь готовый набор пакетов по зависимостям от какого-нибудь мета-пакета `task-*`. есть даже удобная обёртка (из одноимённого пакета) для этого — `tasksel`:

```
$ sudo tasksel
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой подробный и четкий ответ по теме, вы сделали мой день! Я помечу это как ответ. Надеюсь все новички вроде меня, задавшись этим вопросом, будут попадать на эту страницу. У меня остался только один небольшой вопрос, не подскажете название класса программ-панелей, вроде виндового пуска? Конкретные программы я знаю (xfce4-panel например), но нагуглить не могу, запрашиваю "linux panel" вижу в списке гугла только панели управления сервером. Dock панели - не то что мне нужно

Comment: Если не знаете как называется класс этого ПО, может подскажите хотя бы конкретную панель задач (а лучше несколько), не привязанную к конкретному `desktop environment`. Под не привязанностью, я имею в виду автономную работу. Например `xfce4-panel` не автономна, потому что кнопка "Завершить сеанс" не работает без `display manager`'а от xfce, а в "пуске" заготовленные под xfce кнопки, которые без него не работают. Я знаю только о perlpanel, которая очень старая и не поддерживаемая

Comment: @Петр, 1. *de* обычно включает всё необходимое (и *dm*, и *wm*, и всякие элементы, рисующиеся на «рабочем столе»). какие-то из этих компонентов можно заменить (зависит от *de* и от компонента). *wm-ы*, рассчитанные на «автономность» (т.е., без *de*-комбайна), обычно содержат необходимые граф. элементы. 2. то, о чём вы спрашиваете, это *меню*. вроде бы, существуют и полностью автономные программы, не требующие «поддержки» от других компонентов. наверно, их можно найти среди пакетов, содержащих в названии слово `menu`: `$ apt-cache search -n menu`.

Comment: Докладываю. Покопался с разными компонентами, разными ОС, мне ничего не подходит. Не нашел для себя ни одной адекватной комбинации программ, которые сделали бы систему визуально чистой, удобной и простой. Лучшее что я увидел - xfce. Видимо линукс ещё не готов для домашней ОС. Нет даже согласованности в классификации компонентов. Так, например оконный менеджер openbox, кроме своего прямого назначения (представлять окна) имеет ещё какое-то меню которое нормально не убрать, а кастомизация самих окон недостаточная и неудобная.

Comment: Панели либо крайне неудобные, либо привязаны к конкретному окружению, либо давно не поддерживаемые. Всё построено на грязных хаках, некрасиво, неудобно, монолитно и плохо задокументировано. Для себя решил что буду использовать linux только из консоли и через пару лет, когда обзаведусь временем, напишу своё окружение для wayland и выложу в открытый доступ, что бы люди увидели как нужно делать приложения

Comment: Я просто не могу поверить в то, что за столько лет сообщество linux не смогло создать хотя бы одно нормальное окружение. Может быть я просто плохо умею пользоваться поисковыми системами, не знаю, но я не нашел даже ни одного скриншота рабочего стола, который выглядел бы приемлемо. Все они однотипны, меняются только обои.

Answer (score 3):

### Предисловие

Для начала хочу сказать, что вы приняли верное решение попробовать Linux.
В данный момент я приведу пример как установить графическую оболочку **XFCE** 
Я считаю ее самой удобной и практичной, а также в ней нет множества лишних и ненужных программ засоряющих систему, впрочем как вы и хотели.

### Для установки Xfce сделать следующее.

**1**. `sudo apt-get install xfce4` // **установить xfce**

**2**. `sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies` **// установка дополнений**

**3**. `sudo apt-get install task-xfce-desktop` **// установить некоторые** **зависимости**

### **Запуск Xfce**

**1**. `exec ck-launch-session startxfce4`

**2**. `echo 'exec ck-launch-session startxfce4' > ~/.xinitrc` **// добавляем xfce в автозагрузку**

**Затем нужно установить libpam-ck-connector и добавить до `pam_ck_connector.so` в файле /etc/pam.d/common-session такую строчку:**

```
session   optional  pam_loginuid.so
```

### Установка Light Dm (Дисплейный менеджер)

**1**.    `sudo apt-get install lightdm`

**2**.   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: Я перепробовал большинство популярных оболочек. В том числе Xfce. Мне, кстати, xfce понравился больше всего. Но даже в этой оболочке есть недостатки. Мне не понравилась панель, оконный менеджер, не нравится начальный набор программ. Я планирую выяснить наиболее приятную для меня конфигурацию на виртуальной машине, на которой сейчас и произвожу действия, а потом поставить на ноут arch или debian с конфигурацией которая будет чётко задекларирована, а может и упакована в какой-нибудь пакет

Comment: Скажите, что более популярно, GTK или Qt? И могут ли приложения, которые написаны на Qt, работать под GTK?

Comment: этого вам точно сказать не смогу, как то не интересовался, обычно и то и то присутствует в системе для поддержки всего по.

из Arch рекомендую смотреть в сторону Manjaro - великолепный дистрибутив, а по поводу XFCE, вы можете сделать его лучше если что ненравится, вот например https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR2y0xOIIdI

Comment: "Мне не понравилась панель" -- а настраивать-то пробовали? И, ещё раз, сформулируйте что вам нужно и как хочется. Без этого - всё пустой трындёж.

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том, что я не знаю как должен выглядеть процесс сборки

Нет, проблема не в этом.

Не нужно ничего "собирать", возьмите готовый дистрибутив, просто его поставьте и начните заниматься привычными делами. Мой выбор уже много лет (со времён помирания XP) - Linux Mint с XFCE. Но не сосредотачивайтесь на этом. Уже давно прошли те времена, когда Linux ассоциировался исключительно с командной строкой и красноглазием.

> но судя по всему, этого не достаточно,

Достаточно или не достаточно - решать лично вам.

> что бы я получил рабочее окружение

Так с этого и надо начинять! Что для вас "рабочее окружение"? Моё - Eclipse. Всё остальное - рюшечки, включая GIMP и Zandronum.

Comment: Если бы я хотел установить готовое окружение, я бы сделал это. Меня не устраивает ни один набор, а вы пишете не по теме. Здесь я пытаюсь выяснить как собрать своё окружение и какие компоненты для этого необходимы. Изучаю линукс со стороны дизайна и удобства. Мне нравится что его можно кастомизировать и я выясняю, могу ли я собрать линукс так, что бы мне было комфортно его использовать.

Comment: Можно. Собирайте и напишите "по теме". Только сначала разрешите ещё раз поинтересоваться: что такое для вас "своё окружение"?