# Фреймовые оконные менеджеры это часть среды рабочего стола?

Tags: linux

Фреймовые оконные менеджеры ставятся поверх сред рабочего стола? То есть условно установили линукс - ставим гном - ставим i3. Или Фреймовые оконные менеджеры это альтернатива средам рабочего стола, и мы просто ставим линукс - i3?

Не могу пока понять разницу между оконным менеджером и окружением рабочего стола. Окружение это понятие шире, и оно тоже включает в себя оконные менеджеры, но не фреймовые ? Можно ли установить только оконные менеджер, без окружения?

Comment: - "Не могу пока понять разницу..." - Это не вопрос. Вы скажите, что Вы хотите сделать (конкретно!) и что именно не получается. Тогда, может быть, кто-то и ответит.

Comment: Чтобы разницу объяснили :/

Comment: И далее по тексту же есть вопросы. А "не могу понять" лишь подводка

Comment: Честно говоря, никогда не заморачивался подобными вопросами. Но Вы так и не сказали, **зачем** это вам :-) Я точно знаю, что почти все дистрибутивы можно установить либо в серверном варианте - т.е. вообще без гуйни, либо в десктоп варианте - с гуйнёй. В последнем случае можно выбрать конкретный вариант - GNOME, KDE, или куча других. Сейчас можно выбрать ещё между X11 и Wayland. Так что - вариантов много. Выбирайте, что хотите...

Comment: 1. desktop environment (de) — это большой комплекс программ, обязательно включающий, в том числе, и window manager (wm)  (у каждого de он, как правило, свой, а то даже и не один). 2. ну и есть огромное количество «самостоятельных» wm. 3. «фреймовый/нефреймовый» — это способ отображения окон, выбранный разработчиками конкретного wm. 4. [просто к слову](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779642/178576).

Comment: Можно установить Линукс без гуи, поставить условный i3 или другой тайловый менеджер, и все ? Без сред по типу xfce, kde и тд?

Comment: ”без GUI” и «поставить условный i3» — это оксюморон. Каждый вариант в отдельности — можно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И то и другое. Оконные менедлжеры могут работать и вместе с DE и без него.

Например, Гном, кроме менеджера окон, запускает ещё сервисы которые настраивают систему на уровне пользователя и поддерживают некоторое оборудование:

```
RequiredComponents=org.gnome.Shell;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.UsbProtection;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings;
```

И некоторые стандартные сервисы запускаются сами, например, pulse и avahi.

Вот пример запуска i3 поверх гнома https://github.com/regolith-linux/i3-gnome-flashback

Но работа i3 на голых иксах распространенна гораздо сильнее, потому как адепты фреймовых менеджеров предпочитают минимальное окружение. Это установка по умолчанию.